# windows Generating Signed APK not working [react-native]

Tags: android, windows, react-native

sorry for my English, this is my first issues

Hi, I created a issus https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4124

I can run perfect react-native start / react-native run-android and it works great

---

- SO: windows 10
- node: 4.2.2
- npm: 2.14.7
- react-native: 0.1.7

---

I followed this tutorial completely accurate https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

1- the key gender [ok]

[image: 2]

2- Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties [ok]

[image: screenshot_2]

3- Adding signing config to your app's gradle config (android/app/build.gradle)

[image: screenshot_3]

---

launch command ./gradlew assembleRelease

---

The error is as follows
[image: screenshot_1]

did not find the command-native react

[image: screenshot_4]

then we change the absolute path

```
// set up the call to the react-native cli
workingDir reactRoot
commandLine "C:/Users/yo/AppData/Roaming/npm/react-native.cmd", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "false", "--entry-file",
        entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFileRelease, "--assets-dest", resourcesDirRelease
```

in this case, it fails. It is infinite loading

```
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0140Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR151Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Building 79% > :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

---

**test without key file (is exactly the same)**

After testing several commands.

```
./gradlew --info assembleRelease
```

If I wait long at the end I get an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure react-native is installed globally by running install command with **-g** `npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: If you installed on a global basis

react-native init demo
react-native start
react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the build again with --debug or --info options like this

```
./gradlew --debug assembleRelease
                OR
./gradlew --info assembleRelease
```

Usually it gives you some stacktrace to the caused of error.

From my view, I don'e see any problem with your signing config (if you are sure that the password, alias for the keystore file is correct).
I think it is more like a problem with settings for 'react-native'

One more tip, the following line from *android/app/build.gradle* can be removed. As your signing config has name 'release' which will be automatically picked for signing release build. Same case for 'debug' also.

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

So, if you wanna try to build with default keystore to see if it is keystore config problem. You will have to remove all the green highlighted part in **part 3**

Comment: So, it's not a signing config issue but 'react-native' settings. Sorry that I'm not familiar with 'react-native'. Maybe you would want to rename the question title to get help from 'react-native' expert.

Comment: Thanks for answering

After trying everything I gave the same result even without the key file.

I've updated the post with more details.